# How to assign a value inside a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I assign one single entry in a cell array (say the -20)

```
forces = {1,'Static',{'nodal' {2, 2, -30;
                               3, 2, -20 }} };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
forces{3}{2}{2, 3} = -20;
```

Comment: +1 I was just going to post `forces{3}{2}{6}`.  That's all there is to it.